# c# listBox with various elements binded to a list of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I am new to WPF. I have a listBox with various elements graphics elements in it.
The element in the listBox are linked to a list.

[image]

At the moment to add elements I am doing it the old way that is with no binding:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
string currentDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
TextBox tb = new TextBox()
{
    Text = strContent,
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gainsboro),
    IsReadOnly = true,
    ToolTip = strNotes,
    FontSize = 12,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    Width = IMAGES_ROW_HEIGHT,
    Height = IMAGES_ROW_HEIGHT / GOLDEN_RATIO,
    Background = null,
    Margin = new Thickness(BUTTON_MARGIN),
    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
};
sp.Children.Add(tb);
Image newResizedImage = ImageUtilities.StrPath2ResizedImageSizeHeight(strPathImage, IMAGES_ROW_HEIGHT);
if (newResizedImage != null)
{
    sp.Children.Add(newResizedImage);
    sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
}
lbxPPgroups.Items.Add(sp);
lbxPPgroups.SelectedIndex = 0;



var newGroup = new PcDmisData.Group();
newGroup.Description = strContent;
var newImage = new PcDmisData.MyImage();
newImage.Image = newResizedImage;
newImage.IsImageEmbedded = false;

newGroup.myImage = newImage;
newGroup.Notes = strNotes;
easyRunData.olstPPgroups.Add(newGroup);
```

but I know I'm doing it wrong, because I'll have to manually handle deletion, add, reorder of element and so on.
I Would like to be able to bind the elements in the listBox to the elements of the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EasyRunXmlSerializableData
{
    public EasyRunXmlSerializableData()
    { }

    //PcDmis Data           
    public ObservableCollection<PcDmisData.Group> olstPPgroups = new ObservableCollection<PcDmisData.Group>();  
}
```

with

```
public class PcDmisData
{       
    [Serializable]
    public class Group
    {
        public string Description;<---------this for the text of the textbox
        public MyImage myImage;<------------this is the image    
        public string Notes;<---------------this for a tooltip
        public ObservableCollection<PartProgram> partProgramList = new ObservableCollection<PartProgram>();
   }


        [Serializable]
        public class MyImage
        {
            public object Image;
            public bool IsImageEmbedded;
        }

    ....
```

thanx for any help
Patrick

Comment: As asked, the question is too broad. The short version is that you need to learn about data templating, create a view model class that contains the data that will control the visual appearance of a list item and then in XAML declare a `DataTemplate` for your view model type (or types) that bind to the appropriate properties in the view model class and present the desired appearance according to the values in those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links should get you started in the right direction.

You need to understand DataTemplate, and Data Binding for your current scenario.

[MSDN : How to display data in a ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265158(v=vs.95).aspx)

[ListBox tutorial basics](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/)

[ListBox Custom Layout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF)

[How to get a ListBoxItem from a data bound ListBox](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/7#.VlKmAOaffws)

**DataBinding Links**

[DataBinding - How to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752039(v=vs.100).aspx)

[DataBinding - FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx)

[Scott's DataBinding tutorial](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html)